# Dast Authentication Issues in Gitlab CICD on Angular Website

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, owasp

I'm having an issue with the built in gitlab dast scanning and authentication in the pipeline.
The application that is attempting to be scanned is an angular app using the aspnetzero framework.
In gitlab the cicd file uses the dast UI configuration to setup the job and in the cicd yml file the job spec looks like:

```
# Include the DAST template
include:
  - template: DAST.gitlab-ci.yml

# Your selected site and scanner profiles:
dast:
  stage: dast
  dast_configuration:
    site_profile: "auth"
    scanner_profile: "default"
```

In the site profile the proper data is setup for authentication and then running the dast scanning job, I get an error in the logs like

```
2022-07-12T22:00:16.000 INF NAVDB Load URL added to crawl graph
2022-07-12T22:00:16.000 INF AUTH  Attempting to authenticate
2022-07-12T22:00:16.000 INF AUTH  Loading login page LoginURL=https://example.com/account
2022-07-12T22:00:23.000 WRN BROWS response body exceeds allowed size allowed_size_bytes=10000000 request_id=interception-job-4.0 response_size_bytes=11100508 url=https://example.com/main.f3808aecbe8d4efb.js
2022-07-12T22:00:38.000 WRN CONTA request failed, attempting to continue scan error=net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE index=0 requestID=176.5 url=https://example.com/main.f3808aecbe8d4efb.js
2022-07-12T22:00:39.000 INF AUTH  Writing authentication report path=/zap/wrk/gl-dast-debug-auth-report.html
2022-07-12T22:00:39.000 INF AUTH  skipping writing of JSON cookie report as there are no cookies to write
2022-07-12T22:00:40.000 FTL MAIN  Authentication failed: failed to load login page: expected to find a single element for selector css:#manual_login to follow path to login form, found 0
2022-07-12 22:00:40,059 Browserker completed with exit code 1
2022-07-12 22:00:40,060 BrowserkerError: Failure while running Browserker 1.Exiting scan
sion.ExtensionLoader - Initializing Provides the foundation for concrete message types (for example, HTTP, WebSockets) expose fuzzer implementations.
[zap_server] 13499 [ZAP-daemon] INFO  org.parosproxy.paros.extension.ExtensionLoader - Initializing Allows to fuzz HTTP messages.
```

It seems like container that is doing the dast scanning can't properly load the angular javascript file since it exceeds the allowed response size, and the actual login form does not load. Is there a way to increase the allowed size for the request so that we can have the login form properly load.

I've tried various options like setting the stability timeout variables, and even increasing the memory for the ZAP process (`DAST_ZAP_CLI_OPTIONS: '-Xmx3072m'` ). but am still getting the same result in that the login form isn't loading, most likely because the javascript isn't loading properly.

Comment: I dont believe its a ZAP problem, or at least not one I've ever seen. And thats not a ZAP error message...

Answer (score 1):

The fix looks like to be a gitlab/dast cicd variable issue that isn't in any of the current documentation that I could find.

In order to view all the options or parameters available I update the cicd file with the following:

```
include:
  template: DAST.gitlab-ci.yml

dast:
  script:
    - /analyze --help
```

so I could see the options available. From this I was able to find `DAST_BROWSER_MAX_RESPONSE_SIZE_MB` variable to use. Setting that variable fixed my issue